# Java IDE - find all INDIRECT usages/references of a function or class?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, netbeans, jakarta-ee

In Netbeans or in Eclipse, you can use "Find Usages" or "References" from the right click context menu. If a() calls b(), using the functionality from b() will show you a(). However, what I want is to be able to see some kind of tree or have an option to see all usages of a given/class or method, such that if z() calls a() that using the functionality will show both z() and a().

Any IDE plugins or external tools that can do this?

Comment: I have used [this code](http://www.simplethoughtsonline.com/2012/01/representing-java-classes-in-diagrams.html) to **parse class file** and to show them in diagram.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse gives you a way to see Call hierarchy using Ctrl+ Alt + H or choose from the menu like references. 
This should show you the entire call tree for this method.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if this is supported in Netbeans?

Comment: Well my knowledge is only base don google search for netbeans :). I think if you right click on any method it shows you call heirachy option...

Comment: In netbeans, right click context menu has "Call Hierarchy" option. Can be invoked by clicking on a method defintion.

Answer (score 0):

Use PMD or CheckStyle and have it construct an abstract syntax tree.  You can then use that to find indirect usages/references.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, take a look at the Call Hierarchy view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java). It shows all the code associations in one view, which can be further expanded and explored.